# inequality probability between order statistics of two independent distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have two independent distributions $F_1$ and $F_2$ and from each distribution, we draw $k$ variables. Let us represent the $k$ i.i.d. variables from $F_1$ as $\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k\}$. Their order statistics are represented with $\{X_{(1)}, \ldots X_{(k)}\}$. Similarly, $k$ i.i.d. variables drawn from $F_2$ are $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_k$, and their order statistics are represented with $\{Y_{(1)}, \ldots, Y_{(k)}\}$.

Is there any way we can calculate the closed form of the product of these probabilities? $$\Pr (X_{(1)} > Y_{(1)}), \ldots, \Pr(X_{(k)} > Y_{(k)})$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming the two distributions are for continuous random variables, and that they have well behaved probability density functions $f_1, f_2$, then:

$$\Pr(X_{(1)}>Y_{(1)}) = \displaystyle\int_\Bbb R \binom{k}{k}\, (1-F_1(y))^k\, \binom{k}{k-1}\,(1-F_2(y))^{k-1}\,f_2(y)\operatorname d y$$

By reason that we want the probability that all of the $k$ type-1 samples and all but one of the $k$ type-2 samples are larger than the least of the type-2 samples, whatever that is that it is.

Use similar logos to find the rest.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was also thinking in that direction. thanks a lot for editing the question.